# Can wordpress handle uft-8 rewrite rules?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, utf-8, yoast

How can I encode all my url before they got to the wordpress rewrite check?
So  that site.com/**אבד** will convert to site.com **%2F%D7%90%D7%91%D7%93** and only then decide what is the write rule for it.

This is the rewrite rule yoast made for my site. it only work with the encode url.

> (%d7%90%d7%93%d7%9d-%d7%95%d7%97%d7%91%d7%a8%d7%94)/?$    index.php?category_name=$matches[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
function rewrite_rules_decode( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
// Always add your rules to the top, to make sure your rules have priority
global $wp_rewrite;
$tmp_wp_rules = $wp_rewrite->rules;

$decode_wp_rules = array();
foreach ($tmp_wp_rules as $key=>$val){
    $decode_wp_rules[urldecode($key)] = $val;
}
$wp_rewrite->rules = $decode_wp_rules;
//var_dump ($wp_rewrite);
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'rewrite_rules_decode',100);
```